# How to find the orthocenter of a triangle formed by the lines x=2, y=3 and 3x+2y=6 at the point?

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates

I know how to find orthocenter when coordinates of 3 vertices of a triangle is given. But what will be the coordinates of three vertex of the triangle in this question?
what does x=2 and y=3 means? does it mean A(2,0) and B(0,3) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x=2 is the line parallel to y axis and constant value x=2 ( perpendicular to x axis), similarly y=3 is line perpendicular to y axis , with constant y coordinate = 3 and parallel to x axis.

your answer  :

see, basically what you are getting is an right angle triangle. Whose orthocentre is at 2,3 which is vertex of the triangle at the right angle. If you try to draw three lines given, you will get it. Hope it helps.

Comment: so the coordinates are A(2,0) B(2,3) C(0.3). well but still I am not able to find orthocentre of the triangle. I tried to find the slopes of AC and AB. But all in vain. pls assist.

Comment: AB doesn't have a finite slope, since it is a vertical line. Hint: the triangle is a right triangle, which is a special case for orthocenters.

Comment: Thanks. Ya its so simple now the orthocentre is (2,3).

Comment: You understand the term "orthocenter" wrong -- see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthocenter.html) for a proper definition